# Upload/Override the Google Sheet to update the page feed for DSA Campaigns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I need to automate the page feed in the Google Sheet daily for DSA campaigns. I was reading the article which says we can insert maximum 76927 rows in the Google sheet. In my case, I have a multiple csv files which contains 10M of data.

Q: Is it possible to upload/override the csv file in the Google Sheet daily to update the page feed? Override Sheet Example: https://digitalinspiration.com/overwrite-google-drive-files-4467

Q: Is there any other best solution to achieve this goal?

Let us know your thoughts on how I would do it with the API/Google App Script please.

Comment: Can I ask you about the issue of the sample script of the link in your question?

Comment: @tanaike, there is no issue in the sample script, my concern is if I used csv which contains 10M data so can I upload it in the google spreadsheet using above script link?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you confirm about the limitation of Google Spreadsheet? https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603 If the CSV data you want to use is less than the limitation, the CSV data can be uploaded and/or overwritten. How about this?